# Consuming files in UnitTests running in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure-pipelines, devops, mstest

I am running a collection of unit tests in an Azure DevOps Pipeline. The unit testing framework in use is MSTest.

Some unit tests load files that are inside the repo. Therefore the Property `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Copy Always`.
Down below you can see the property being set inside the `csproj` file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <!-- shortened csproj file -->

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="TestFiles\sample.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

### Test Method

Inside the test, the file gets loaded as seen in the next code block.

```cs
var path = Path.Join("TestFiles", "sample.xml");
var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
```

#### Local Run

> I set the `verbosity` to `detailed` in order to see if the file gets copied or not.

Running `dotnet test .\Project\Project.csproj --logger trx --verbosity detailed` locally, everything works as expected with the test results.
Same applies for running the tests in Visual Studio.

#### Pipeline

I execute the tests inside an Azure DevOps Pipeline with the `DotNetCoreCLI` task.

```yaml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run Unit Tests
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: Project/Project.csproj
    arguments: --verbosity detailed
```

I extracted the generated command from the pipeline logs: `/usr/bin/dotnet test /home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/Project.csproj --logger trx --results-directory /home/vsts/work/_temp --verbosity detailed`. I don't see any significant differences between my local command compared to the one being generated by the pipeline.

##### MSBuild

Indeed inspecting the local **and** Azure DevOps Pipeline logs, the file gets copied as expected.

```
Copying file from "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/TestFiles/sample.xml" to "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/TestFiles/sample.xml".
```

##### Test Error

The path matches the one from the MSBuild log `/home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/TestFiles/sample.xml`. Then again, I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/TestFiles/sample.xml'.
```

##### *Pipeline debugging*

I tried to list all files inside the output directory adding the `continueOnError` key to the test task.

```yaml
# ...
tasks:
# ...
- script: ls -la /home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0
- script: ls -la /home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0/TestFiles
```

The first script action already fails with the following error message:

```
ls: cannot access '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/bin/Debug/net6.0': No such file or directory
```

> At this point I'm just lost and don't know what to do about this seemingly simple problem... Any suggestions how I get the files containing test data to the unit test? Where is my mistake?

### Update 1

I tried to switch to xUnit. But it gave me the same `FileNotFoundException` as before. I don't think it's a problem with the test itself but with the Azure DevOps Pipeline environment.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `[DeploymentItem]` attribute that you can use to access files in tests?

Comment: I am not. It was previously on the test method. But I removed it since I don't really understand what that attribute does under the hood. Is it okay to load the file manually?

Comment: It just copies the file to a test/out folder so that it is easily accessible. I'm sure you can make it happen manually but its more work for yourself.

Comment: @Crowcoder I just ran the pipeline again with the `DeploymentItem` Attribute as discussed. Changed the path accordingly and I still get the same exception.

Comment: If your test is reading files, it is **not** a unit test, it is an integration test. If you want your test to be a unit test, refactor it to mock the file system. Unit tests have no external dependencies, which includes the file system.

Comment: @DanielMann Unit test or integration test. MSTest apparently allows for `DeploymentItems` which leads me to believe that having files as *external dependencies* is a valid use case for MSTest `TestMethods`.
I really wanna know why I can't access the files in the `Build.BinariesDirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further debugging of the pipeline, I found a mistake I caused myself.

When debugging the pipeline I used the `- script: ls -la /home/vsts/work/1/s/Project/...` task. The path I specified was the one from this post (which I abstracted from the real thing cuz its from work yk) **NOT** the actual one of my test project.
Listing a non existing directory does not work for obvious reasons...

Comparing the paths from the MSBuild log message and the actual test run showed that they were almost identical. The actual file had a lowercase extension and the file name inside the test project was uppercase.
Running the pipeline in the `ubuntu-latest` environment means that we are working with a case sensitive file system (unlike on my local machine which is a Windows 11 machine).

> **tl;dr** - Everything was correct, I just got to match the actual file name and file path inside the consuming test 100% correctly or run it in a windows environment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).